# Changing Screen After hitting specific score

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to change my Game screen into the Game Over Screen once one player hits a score of 3. In my pong file, I have the following. Gameover_state is a global variable.

```
def main():
while running:
    #Code and event based things 

    #if the score reaches 3, then the game is over
    if player_paddle.score == 3 or ai_paddle.score == 3:
        gameover_state = True
```

In my screens file which controls how screens change to another, I have this in my Gamestate screen:

```
class GameScene(SceneBase):
    def __init__(self):
        SceneBase.__init__(self)


    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                # Move to the next scene when the user pressed Enter 
                self.SwitchToScene(GameOverScene())

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                print("You are hitting up!") 
                print(self.next)


    def Update(self):
        #pongtry4.main()



        if pongtry4.gameover_state == True:
            self.SwitchToScene(GameOverScene())

        pongtry4.main()

    def Render(self, screen):
        # The game scene is just a blank blue screen 
        #screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
        pass
```

I've tried debugging and my gameover_state eventually returns true after either ai or player gets 3. However, the gamestate doesn't change properly to the game over screen. Is the problem the order of how I call pongtry4.main() or something else? Thanks.

Comment: use `print()` to display values in different variables and which part of code is executed - it helps to see what's going on in code.

Comment: You have to help us by turning your program into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy, run and test, otherwise it's difficult or impossible to understand how your code works.

Comment: I checked code in previous questions and I don't know why do you use `pongtry4.main()` - it seems it has code which should be splited into 'ProcessInput()`, `Update()`, `Render()`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do Is first place that game scene into a event handler:

```
loop = True # This Variable is global
loop2 = True
while loop:
    GameScene.processInput(# args)
    GameScene.Update(# args)
    GameScene.render(# args)
''' Inside the function, once a certain score is reached, loop is declared 
false'''
while loop2:
    # place other scene here
pygame.quit()
```

You could implement this inside the main function, and thats it.